# Validation in Dynamic Forms in VueJs

Tags: forms, vue.js, dynamic, vuejs2

I can't add Validations:{} in my dynamic form in VueJs. In  My data()  has a employees[] array

---

```html
<input type="email" for='email' id='email' 
                    class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Email" 
                     v-model='employee.email'
                     @input='$v.WhatIWriteHere.$touch()' >
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no any class called `validation:{}` you can use `watch(){}` class for check if input validated or simple send data to server validate if wrong return error with code 422

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return {
             employees: [
              {
                name  : '',
                number: '',
                email :'',
                about: ''
              }
            ],
          yuborildi: false,
            email:"" 
            }
    },
    validations:{
     
           // I don't know how I require my email
      
    },
```